# Tags are too low-contrast to be readable

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) It's now fixed.

---

What if I want to do code reviews on a laptop at the beach?  How am I supposed to read this in bright sunlight?

[image: Screenshot of some tags]

In seriousness, this is problematic for users with less-than-perfect vision.

Comment: Why would you use a laptop at the beach? You're on a beach enjoy time away from a computer...geez!

Comment: less beach, more snowy mountains? The sun levels are similar :D

Comment: @bluefeet: Code-reviewing takes no breaks! *takes laptop into shower*

Answer (score 2):

The original screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of some tags]

The revised version:

[image: Screenshot with revision]